# How does a computer keep track of Ram?

Tags: memory, ram

So I know the operating system must be in control of giving an application a certain amount of Ram.  But I'm curious how does it know how much to give to the application,  and how does it know how much the said application is using?  Like who and what is keeping track of that usage? And how does it know which memory is safe to use? I assume that some memory is reserved for critical systems.  I must admit that I don't have very much knowledge of operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operating system divides memory into "pages". They're typically 4KB in size.

The operating system keeps track of those pages in a table. By counting them we can determine how much memory is used or free.

Userland programs request memory by a system call. It depends on the system, and `mmap()` is used for Linux. This will request the OS to give an empty page to use for the program. Freeing the memory is basically the reverse.